# C# How to serialize (JSON, XML) normal properties on a class that inherits from DynamicObject

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, dynamicobject

I am trying to serialize an instance of a class that inherits from DynamicObject. I've had no trouble getting the dynamic properties to serialize (not demonstrated here for brevity), but "normal" properties don't seem to make the trip. I experience the same problem regardless of serialization class: it's the same for JavaScriptSerializer, JsonConvert, and XmlSerializer.

```
public class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    public string MyNormalProperty { get; set; }
}

...

MyDynamicClass instance = new MyDynamicClass()
{
    MyNormalProperty = "Hello, world!"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance);
// the resulting string is "{}", but I expected to see MyNormalProperty in there
```

Shouldn't MyNormalProperty show up in the serialized string? Is there a trick, or have I misunderstood something fundamental about inheriting from DynamicObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the DataContract/DataMember attributes from `System.Runtime.Serialization`

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string MyNormalProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

This way the serialisation will work no matter what serialiser you use...

Answer (score 3):

Just use `JsonProperty` attribute

```
public class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    [JsonProperty("MyNormalProperty")]
    public string MyNormalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:** `{"MyNormalProperty":"Hello, world!"}`

Comment: Thank you -- this works and would have done it if I were developing strictly with Newtwonsoft.Json. :)