# Empty result when converting DynamicObject to JSON

Tags: c#, json, dynamicobject

I've got a class inherited from `DynamicObject`. It contains all the properties stored in `List<MyProperty>`:

```
public class MyObject : DynamicObject
{
    public List<MyProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
public class MyProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize it to JSON using Newtonsoft Json. But after converting it I get an empty object: `{}`. When I remove inheritance from DynamicObject, I get all my properties serialized as a JSON array. And that's exactly what I need. How can I serialize my class without removing that inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by overriding the `GetDynamicMemberNames` method:

```
public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
{
    yield return nameof(this.Properties);
}
```

Now it serializes just as I need.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, either or both of these solutions should solve your problem:

```
public class MyObject : DynamicObject
{
    [JsonProperty("MyList")]
    public List<MyProperty> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject : DynamicObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<MyProperty> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822121/c-sharp-how-to-serialize-json-xml-normal-properties-on-a-class-that-inherits).