# Web api ignore original property while serializing object inheriting from DynamicObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In asp.net web api core 1.0 (*I hope same as in asp.net web api 2.0*), while serializing an object which is **inherited from DynamicObject** ignores the class's own declared properties.

```
public class Demo : DynamicObject
{
 // This property is ignore in api response
 public int Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

**Actual Json:**

```
 {"DynamicProp1": "abc", "DynamicProp2" : 123 ... so on}
```

**Expected Json:**

```
{"Prop1": 123, "DynamicProp1": "abc", "DynamicProp2" : 123 ... so on}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you put the return object? I mean, if you initialize your variable as DynamicObject then it acts as it is expected.

Comment: I just got a solution. Thanks. Posting the solution as answer myself

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I got a solution

```
[DataContract]
public class Demo : DynamicObject
{
 // This property is ignore in api response
 [DataMember]   OR [JsonProperty]
 public int Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822121/c-sharp-how-to-serialize-json-xml-normal-properties-on-a-class-that-inherits).